# Sony IMX111PQ Datasheet

Tags: datasheet, nexus-4

I am using the Nexus 4 for augmented reality applications.

The cellphone features the Sony IMX111PQ CMOS sensor.
Do you know where i should search for the datasheet describing the progressive scan patter of this CMOS sensor, online?
I found this flyer http://www.sony.net/Products/SC-HP/cx_news/vol65/pdf/imx081_091_111pq.pdf
but it is not as informative as a technical datasheet.

Thank you

Comment: Did you found it? I realy need it too! Especially the spectral attributes.

Comment: I even e-mailed Sony and Sony engineers and did not hear back. Please let me know if you get something.